# GCP managed SSL certificate stuck at FAILED_RATE_LIMITED?

Tags: ssl, https, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to issue a SSL certificate for my loadbalancer, which serves traffic to an application hosted on GKE cluster in the backend. I have reserved a static IP for the loadbalancer, and I am able to access the application over HTTP.

Early this week, I had managed to generate SSL certificates and attached it to the load balancer using the GCP managed SSL certificates, and my domain was working on HTTPS network. However I had to delete the loadbalancer and launch it again using the Kubernetes Ingress. But now I am not able to apply the certificates to the loadbalancer. The certificates fail to provision with the error: **FAILED_RATE_LIMITED**.

Now I have deleted all the previously generated certificates on my account, and there is a single certificate now. According to the error, I have exhausted the number of GCP managed SSL certificates on my account. But I have deleted all the previously generated certs and I have almost waited for 10-11 hours, but the issue still exists. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FAILED\_RATE\_LIMITED - Google managed SSL certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58538300/failed-rate-limited-google-managed-ssl-certificate)