# FAILED_RATE_LIMITED - Google managed SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform

It's been stuck on this status for over a day and I'm unable to successfully provision a new managed SSL certificate (to attach to a load balancer)

Google docs say to contact support but we're not on any role / plan (small company), does anyone know if this limit resets after certain period of time? Or a way for customers without a support plan to resolve?

Using terraform to deploy a complete web application if that helps, this includes all the load balancer parts, managed instance group, template, ssl policy etc, I would destroy and bring up the entire project to ensure I haven't missed any settings, but after a few re-deployments I trigger this rate limit :(

Try again after a full day has passed, getting worried this is not resolvable without paying for a support plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note that the Google managed SSL certificates are based on [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/) 
Let’s Encrypt provides rate limits to ensure fair usage, the main limit is Certificates per Registered Domain (50 per week).

The Failed Validation have a limit of 5 failures per account, per hostname, per hour.  You can use the [Staging Environment](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/staging-environment/) to increase the limit to 60 fails per hour if you need more flexibility.

As you can see in the [Creating and Using SSL Certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#domain-status) this error means that you may temporarily be rate-limited and you do need to contact with Google to discuss your limit.

If you want to contact GCP support you can always try the [Free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier). Then if you are happy with the support and you need it you can get a paid support after ending the free trial.

If you don’t want to use this way to contact with google you can always try to get some visibility to your issue using the [Report Issue with Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Comment: thanks, it resolved itself after a few days, bad habit of using terraform to completely destroy and rebuild things, stuff like this I'll handle and treat as somewhat stateful!